# Dynamically update the corresponding price when a size is selected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my online shop a big size can be more expensive than a small one. 
So when the user select his size, I would like to update the price in the product show.

By default I display the Product's price.  Variant's size can have a different price...

Here is my form, in my product show.

```
<h4 id="product_price"><%= number_to_currency_euro @product.price %></h4>
  <%= form_tag admin_sale_items_path , input_html: {id: "salesform"} do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :product_id, @product.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, @token %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :quantity, 1 %>
      <%= select_tag :variant_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@product_size_options, :id, :size_and_color_stock), class: 'custom-select variant', required: true %>

    <%= submit_tag, class: "btn-main btn-block", id: "add_to_basket" %>
  <% end %>
```

I am not comfortable with jQuery and js so i'd need your help with explanation please :)

here is my try

```
$('#salesform').bind(".variant").bind('ajax:success', function(){
    $('#product_price').html("<%= #the variant price %>");
});
```

How should I retrieve the selected size, to use it and find its price?

Comment: You are trying more difficult code ! Just simply add this in the Ajax success function ! $('#product_price').html("<%= variant.stocks.last.price %>");

Comment: Each Ajax has a success handler function, in Jquery.Like $.ajax({data:{},url:"DEMO URL",success:(data)=>{YOUR LOGIC}});

Comment: shall i write these lines in a show.js.erb  ?

Comment: Yes right. Wherever you are writing the Ajax call, just add succss handler. This is the simplest API of it http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I am not getting it sorry

Comment: Have you written any ajax method call ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you haven't written any ajax method call. 
Try writing an Ajax call like this,

```
$.ajax({
data : DATA_YOU_WANT_TO_PASS_TO_URL,
url : https://DATA-PROVIDER-URL,
success : function (data){
$('#product_price').html("<%= #the variant price %>");
// YOUR OTHER LOGIC for success handler
}
```

Comment: how can I define `data:`  `url:`  ? When I select the variant (size color) it need to find the corresponding price in another table...